# R: Test if variables contain the same informaton

Tags: r

Let's say I have two variables in a data set that containing the same information, like "male" and "female" (assuming only 2 sexes and no missing data). How can I test that the two columns contain the same information, thereby allowing me to delete one of them?

I thought about checking the rank of a matrix containing them, but apparently such a matrix is full rank, even though the columns are clearly dependent on each other.

EDIT: I mean two variables such as the following:

```
M F
1 0
1 0
0 1
0 1
1 0
```

Clearly the same information is contained within these two variables. How do I test for that?

Comment: Hi Noah, can you give an example of what you mean? Do you mean that the columns are identical (same values, same order), or just that they have the same factor levels?

Comment: If you wanted to use the rank of the matrix you need to add a column of 1s.  If you add that then the rank of the resulting matrix will still only be 2 instead of 3 even though there are three columns.

Comment: For the example presented, they will have a correlation of 1 or -1, so you can test which are redundant with `apply(cor(df), 1, function(x){any(abs(x) == 1)})`, though if there's multiples you'll have to go look at `cor(df)` to figure out how they're paired.

Comment: is the sample space of the two columns binary in nature?

Comment: @alistaire That was great insight, and I implemented it as such. For others who might come across this, you'll want to use `all.equal()` instead of `==` for checking. If anyone sees a potential flaw in this method let me know, but it definitely accomplishes what I want it to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

Based on your clarification, you can use pairwise correlations to detect positive and negative correlations between the data columns, for example:

```
# create example data matrix matrix; add a fourth column that is inverse
# of the third one
> set.seed(1)
> x <- matrix(sample(0:1, 15, replace=TRUE), ncol=3)
> x <- cbind(x, ifelse(x[,3] == 0, 1, 0))
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1    0
[4,]    1    1    0    1
[5,]    0    0    1    0
```

Next, construct a correlation matrix. The diagonal is set to zero since to ignore self-correlations.

Then, we test each columns to see if the maximum absolute value of its correlation with other columns equals one, which would indicate the the columns contain the same information.

```
> cormat <- cor(x)
> diag(cormat) <- 0
> apply(cormat, 2, function(x) { max(abs(x)) == 1 })
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I don't mean identical columns, I mean columns where, for example, v1 = 1 - v2

Comment: Have you considered using correlation between the two columns?

Comment: @Noah, updated to reflect clarification. The above is based on the second suggestion from my original answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?

```
x = rep(c("Male"), each = 10)
y = rep(c("Female"),each = 10)
fm = matrix(data = c(x,y), ncol = 2)

fm[,1] == fm[,2]
```

Comment: No, that just tests whether each value in one column equals the corresponding value in the other. I want to test if the variables are redundant in information, not equal in value.