# How to compare two columns in a dataframe with opposite values

Tags: r, statistics, data-visualization, data-cleaning

In a data frame, I would like to compare two columns that have opposite values, is there a way to check or even visualize it?

```
Col1 | Col2
------------
  T  |   F 
  F  |   T 
  T  |   F 
  T  |   F
```

Comment: How do you want to summarize the two columns?

Comment: I want to check if they are the same by providing evidence. Because these two are the target columns. If they are the same, I will drop one of them and let the other be my target column for modeling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Test if variables contain the same informaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070460/r-test-if-variables-contain-the-same-informaton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

Update: See @akrun's comment:

```
df %>% mutate(isOpposite = Col1 == Col2)
```

```
df %>% 
  mutate(isOpposite = ifelse(Col1 == Col2, TRUE, FALSE))
```

```
   Col1  Col2 isOpposite
1  TRUE FALSE      FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE      FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE      FALSE
4  TRUE FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: You may also use `df %>% mutate(isOpposite = Col1 == Col2)`